Catch DbUpdateException and Looks for is UniqueValidationError or not?
I am catching DBUpdateExcdeption. My purpose is checking for is it UNIQUE VALIDATION ERROR or not.
I tried to convert InnerExcdeption to SqlExceptionbut didnt worked.
public static bool IsExceptionUniqueConstraintViolation(Exception ex)
{
    var sqlException = ex.InnerException as SqlException;

    if (sqlException.Number == 2601 || sqlException.Number == 2627)
       return true;

    return false;
}

What is wrong?

The inner exception is most likely not a SqlException so the as conversion will fail (see as operator documentation). When the conversion fails, the result will be null.
When you have nested exceptions, it's possible that there is more than 1 level of nesting, so you might have a SqlException more than one level down - you can just assume the inner exception will be a SqlException if the exception is thrown by code within a library.
You also want to add in a check for if the exception really is a SqlException:
if (ex.InnerException is SqlException)
{
    var sqlException = (SqlException)ex.InnerException;

    if (sqlException.Number == 2601 || sqlException.Number == 2627)
       return true;
} 

return false;


Yes your first paragraph is correct, returns null. I tried second paragrapph mentioned but second inner exception is also coming null.

@MusaAKYUZ More than 1 means there could be 2, 3, 4, 5 or more nest exceptions. You can't just check the nearest inner exception.

Yeah it nested. In my exception; The main exception has Inner Exception with "Number" properties is 2627. But ı can't reach the number property

I am wiritng ex.InnerException.Number but don't works

Oh ı solved. Problem is when ı am tring to convert with var sqlException = ex.InnerException as SqlException; is correct but the SqlException librariy is not matching with Syste.Data.SqlClient. In DbUpdateException's inner exception is Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlExceptionCollection

I changed my library to using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
